# Dispatch in useEffect not being dispatched on first load of component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, use-effect

I'm running the following code in my main (App) component.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (cookies.darkMode !== undefined) {
      const cookieResult =
        cookies.darkMode.toLowerCase() === 'true' ? true : false
      dispatch(switchTheme(cookieResult))
    } else {
      dispatch(switchTheme(prefersDarkMode))
    }
  })
```

In first load of the App component it executes the code inside the useEffect except it's not dispatching anything.

I have no clue why so any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Would you like to run this snippet and share console log?

`
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('FIRST');
    if (cookies.darkMode !== undefined) {
      const cookieResult =
        cookies.darkMode.toLowerCase() === 'true' ? true : false
      dispatch(switchTheme(cookieResult))
    } else {
      dispatch(switchTheme(prefersDarkMode))
    }
    console.log('SECOND');
  })
`

Comment: @FrozenICE Thank you for the comment! I tried and both 'FIRST' and 'SECOND' are printed multiple times so it seems the function is working but nothing is being dispatched.

Comment: I checked and it's not executing my action for some reason I can't figure out why :(

Comment: Where did you define `prefersDarkMode` and `cookies`?

Comment: Apparently my reducer wasn't being loaded properly. I've fixed thank you for your help!